# How to delete ender dragon in unloaded chunks - overworld

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

This is a problem I've had in my creative world.
Recently, I was stupid enough to teleport myself to somewhere about 100k blocks from spawn in the overworld and try to kill the ender dragon.
It didn't turn out well because it quickly flew away faster than I could kill it.
It turned out that it flew into unloaded chunks and I couldn't chase after it.
I know ender dragons can fly to spawn in the overworld, and I have tried `/kill @e[type=Minecraft:ender_dragon]`, however, it hasn't worked.

I am scared that it will travel to spawn, and destroy my builds.
However, even if it doesn't as it is in unloaded chunks, I would like to remove it from my world.
I roughly know the coordinates where it flew to but I don't know exactly. If possible, I would prefer to **not** fly out and find it again.

It may have already despawned but I'm not too sure.
Any help to remove it would be greatly appreciated! :D

Comment: I also did ``/gamerule mobgriefing false`` just in case. But I would still like to remove the dragon :)

Answer (score 1):

If the chunk is unloaded, the dragon can't move. Only mobs in loaded chunks can move.

Comment: Thanks. I was worried since the dragon is a boss mob it might be able to. Preferably I still want a way to get rid of it xD

Comment: All right, I think I have a solution. When I get a chance I'll check.

Answer (score 1):

If your scared, make a repeating command block at spawn that does`/kill @e[type=Minecraft:ender_dragon]`. Make sure it's always active and repeating. If it's not at spawn, make sure to force load the chunk using `/forceload add ~ ~`. This will instantly kill the dragon once it's loaded in.

Comment: Oh and make sure to do /gamerule commandBlockOutput false

Answer (score -1):

I'd give myself speed 100 and/or an elytra and fireworks, get really far ahead of the dragon, then type in the command `/kill @e[type=ender_dragon]` and wait until it's in your field of view to execute it.

Comment: I tried to do that but I lost the dragon. :P

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure then. Try upping your render distance, and if it doesn't work, then well, I'd say that you can't and your spawn is screwed. Actually, try giving yourself strength 255 and hitting it with a sharpness 5 diamond sword. It's the only thing I could think of.